# Как в редакторе Atom назначить горячие клавиши для сниппетов?

Tags: atom, hotkeys

Раньше сниппеты вызывались сочетанием alt-shift-s (причем в списке кейбиндингов тоже нет), теперь почему-то перестали (из контекстного меню вызываются, но это крайне неудобно). Как назначить на хоткеи сниппеты?
Спасибо.